SCSS takes over the rendering of text in Se Web Driver Tests
This is now resolved.  Yes, XPath fixes it but finding where to fix it and why, from Inspect in Dev Tools, that's another thing.  I have notes in the next several slides of the data trail followed and what filled gaps in my knowledge along the way.
Part of the confusion was not being able to modify the text in ng-reflect-model, which is where text typed into the text box ends up:

Reading this link, Selenium with Kendo UI, more closely and just taking the leap of faith that Inspect takes one to the nested input nested in kendo-textbox and just below the span element, this is where the following x-path was figured out:

Looking at the the form via Inspect, and trying to piece this together, can really get one lost fast.  There's a bit of Angular directive technology at work here, that's another leap of faith -- 'The Kendo Team has this!' :) is pretty much what I realized. Here is an input element where the input won't show up.  But you have the test target this element and it will.
================ New Content 21 Nov 13:35 =============
5:45 PM found this SO post: Selenium with Kendo UI
Is the 'hard way' of writing xpath in C# the way to do this, using Se Web Driver?  The post is 6 years old ... there's not a better way?
Also posted this on the Kendo Textbox forum, crossing my fingers, there's an easier way than running the test, letting it fail, mapping out x-path, rinse-lather-repeat, eventually get there? :)
==================== Above New info as of 5:45 20 Nov =====================
When the test runs, here is how the first name really looks.  Due to no entry on the left, the error icon shows up.  The first name is in the  element on the right.  Not where it should be.

After a test run, I typed in the text in the correct place myself.

This is where the test should be putting the text. I have no idea where the span.k-input-suffix comes from.  Searching the VS solution, no such class shows up.  Searching for span.k finds many entries, none of which match the class shown.
Here is the code for the test:
        public class SeleniumCourseWebDriverTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void SimpleDoITWebDriverTests()
    {
        var driver = new EdgeDriver();
        driver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(1200, 1087);
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost:5000/login?returnUrl=%2Fhome");
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".flexbox-container")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".btn")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("WindowsAuthentication")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.Name("Recognize a Team Member")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Award Submission")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("shouterFirstName")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.Name("First Name")).SendKeys("Michael");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("shouterLastName")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("shouterLastName")).SendKeys("Durthaler");

Text areas also have a lot of involved SCSS in play but they work:

Here are the 2 lines of code for this text area:
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("awardCommentsText")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("awardCommentsText")).SendKeys(" Ian was a great help figuring out why my courses in my Edge browser were freezing up.");

From what I can tell, SCSS is just taking over text boxes and doing mysterious invention of classes, which can't be found for some reason.
Here is the HTML for the First Name text box:
        <div class="col-md">
  <kendo-label text="First Name">
    <kendo-textbox
                   name="First Name"
                   id="shouterFirstName"
                   contenteditable="true"
                   >

    </kendo-textbox>
  </kendo-label>
</div>

Here is HTML for the comments text area, where rendering works:
    <div col-md>
  <kendo-label
               id="awardtext"
               [for]="awardtext"
               text="Comments">
  </kendo-label>
  <textarea kendoTextArea #awardtext id="awardCommentsText" contenteditable="true"> </textarea>
</div>

I have no idea where the extra  to the right end of the text boxes comes from.  This isn't happening for text areas.
Am at a loss, if this is not enough info, let me know and I'll try to explain better.
Here is further info that may help.  Where the text is being crammed into the right end of text boxes, in some 'mysterious' span, these spans are where validation indicators show up.
The ones outlined in red, show up as they should if the form is typed regularly.  The check mark indicates the entries have a certain length.  If there's no entry, then ! appears in red where the check mark is.
For some reason, when the Se test runs, despite ids being set for where the text is shown now, the test instead finds where the validators live.  And crams the text in the validators' spans.
Date picker, does the same thing.  I can type the date in or selected it and all is good.  Send Keys with "11/20/2024" into it, and the date string appears where validators would, crammed in to the right of the calendar icon.
SCSS seems to think 'Ah, Yes! This is where these keys (text characters) belong!'  So it snags them and puts them there.
Maybe this gives a new clue to help out those observing this?
It's a weird one where we have to step back and realize "Computers do what they're told to do, and only what they're told to do".  And then get clues and find out why.
Thanks again for any ideas.


See the top most notes entered in the post.  Not getting too involved in what is going on under the hood with Angular here is important.  It was easy to get lost in all the fascinating stuff happening in the F12 Inspect window!
Even though the input wasn't showing what was typed, the value was getting into the ng-reflect-model as the value just above this input.
I wasn't sure x-path would fix it as the input itself wasn't already showing the typed text. But ... angular directive technology has already been put into play by Telerik / Kendo.  Don't doubt those guys with those long swords -- they know what they're doing.
Hope this helps any others needing a bit more insight using Se Tests.
I plan to ask the Kendo team for input for a more rounded experience, I hope anyone reading this does the same.

I think you should edit the notes into your answer instead of editing your question, makes it easier to separate problem and answer
